# Bind wpf textbox to selectedItem of listBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have two classes

```
Class A
{
     public int something { get; set; }
     public B classB = new B();
}


Class B
{
     public int anotherThing { get; set; }
}
```

I have ObservableCollection from Class A

```
public ObservableCollection<A> listOfClasses = new ObservableCollection<A>();
```

Now, I have listbox that is binded to listOfClasses

```
                    <ListBox x:Name="justAList" SelectionMode="Extended">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=something}"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListBox>
```

And of course the binding.

```
justAList.ItemsSource = listOfClasses ;
```

So far everything works. I'm able to see the list with its items (I'm adding the items to the list with some other method).
My question is, I want to have another textbox and bind it to the anotherThing int in Class B. How can it be done?

Comment: Can you tell where the text will be? But it should be `{Binding Path=classB.anotherThing}` if you are planning to add it to the list item

Comment: Its going to be on a different section in the xaml, a stack or wrap panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to `make` an instance of `class B a property` in case you want binding support:

```
private B classB = new B();
public B ClassB
{
   get
   {
      return classB;
   }
   set
   {
      classB = value;
   }
}
```

And now you can bind to TextBox like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ClassB.anotherThing}"/>
```

Make sure TextBox `DataContext` is set to some instance of ClassA.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in comments you want to bind `TextBox Text` with `SelectedItem instance`, which can be achieved this way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=justAList, 
                        Path=SelectedItem.ClassB.anotherThing}"/>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want each item in the listOfClasses will have different values in the textbox, so Item 1 in the listOfClasses will have 1 in anotherThing int, and item 2 will have 2 in anotherThing (for instance)

Comment: Where exactly you want this TextBox to be placed?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, but i'll try anyway: on a different groupbox/stack/wrappanel

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. ListBox binded to collection of `A` and textBox needed to be bind to property in `B` but for which instance of class A, you want this binding. Suppose you have 10 items in list, then textBox will be binded to which instance? Please add more details.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough. Anyway I managed to do that by the following:
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElemantName=justAList, Path=SelectedItem.classB.anotherThing}"/>, but your answer lead me to the full answer, so thanks for that.

Comment: Now its more clear that you want to bind to SelectedItem instance. Perhaps mentioning it in question would have help. Anywyas you get it. So either you can accept this answer or post other answer so that question can be closed. I will mention update in my answer.